# How to bind a field with AngularJS that was added dynamically with jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

So, I have a form with fields added dynamically with jQuery, that fields have `ng-model`, but they are not compiled by AngularJS. How can I bind/compile those fields?

Exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/J48fA/1/

[edit1] ps: I'm on RailsApp with complex cocoon insert fields. I'm using AngularJS to show a table with many info about the fields, so, I'm trying to use it without touch in the rails code.

Comment: More simply, why don't you have AngularJS add those fields? That way you don't have to worry about binding

Comment: why do you need to manipulate using JQuery. Use angularJS directives for DOM manipulation.

Comment: @EliteOctagon I'm on RailsApp with complex cocoon insert fields. I'm using AngularJS to show a table with many info about the fields, so, I'm trying to use it without touch in the rails code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with all of the previous comments.  It is best practice to use directives for any DOM manipulation.  With that being said, this is how you would accomplish what you are trying to do if you want to do it within the controller.

You need to pass in the $compile service into your controller, and then add the few lines of code that I added:

```
testapp.controller('parentController', ['$scope', '$window', '$compile', function($scope, $window, $compile) {

    var $elementToAppend = $('<input ng-model="fields[1].value" type="text" value="">');
    $compile($elementToAppend)($scope);
    $('#field-1').append($elementToAppend);
    $scope.fields = {};
    fields = $scope.fields;

    $scope.buildField = function (id){
        $scope.fields[id] = {'value' : null};
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear that!